# Is there more competition for postdoc/faculty positions in the biological sciences, compared to similar positions in the health sciences?

Tags: job-search, postdocs, faculty-application, medicine, biology

I am seeking advice/input from graduate students and faculty within the fields of health sciences and integrative physiology/biology regarding employment opportunities, competition, and compensation in each field. 
My research has led me to believe that the health sciences has more job opportunities/flexibility, less competition, and higher compensation for a given position when compared to the life sciences.

Are post-doctorate positions necessary in the biological sciences to earn a faculty position at a tier 1, research-intensive state university?

Is it true that there is far more competition for post-doctorate/faculty positions in the biological sciences at these institutions when compared to similar positions in the health sciences?

Comment: "State universities", even within the US, include a broad range of very different institutions.  Can you be a little more specific about what sort of institution / career you have in mind, and in what country?

Comment: @NateEldredge, My most desired position would be a tenure-track faculty position at a research-intensive, T1 state university. My passion is research. I enjoy human-subject research, but I also enjoy in vitro investigations. I really have no preference there. I would be open to taking a position outside of the U.S.

Comment: Voted to reopen after edits. What exactly is "health science"? Do you mean medicine?

Comment: @CapeCode, Our particular program does not offer an M.D., although that will be happening in the next couple of years. Our program has students and professors from fields such as health physics, biomechanics, cognition/neurophysiology, human physiology, physical therapy, public health, and epidemiology.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer your first question from my own experience as someone who earned a PhD in Biomedical Sciences from a top-level research medical school in the United States, and spent much of his long academic career on the faculty of health sciences at a major research university. (Others may have had different opinions based on their own experiences.)

> My research has led me to believe that the health sciences has more
> job opportunities/flexibility, less competition, and higher
> compensation for a given position when compared to the life sciences.

This is absolutely true. Basically, it comes down to money available for research. In academia, this money comes primarily from government funding. The NIH, which funds health sciences, has MUCH more funding to distribute, and in larger amounts, than the NSF, which funds biological sciences in general. And of course, there is big pharma and other health care industries having plentiful funds for research and development.

Health sciences professors, who are almost always on the faculties of schools of medicine and other health sciences, are more highly paid than biology-related professors, who usually are on the faculties of schools of liberal arts and sciences.

And yet, perhaps surprisingly, health science positions, though rigorous in their requirements, are generally less competitive (i.e., less applicants per position opening) than in life sciences. This is because fewer PhDs have the clinical/biomedical/health backgrounds that health sciences schools are looking for.